# WIX installer for WCF windows service

Tags: c#-4.0, installation, wix3.11

I have WCF service which i can build and test(install from CMD Installutill) from WCF client successfully. Now i created a wix installer project to create a exe for the same WCF service. Following is the WIX code i have used:

```
 <Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="TestWCFService">
  <Component Id="TestWCFService.exe" Guid="F071A592-33A9-44DA-A81B-AD4AC8195757">
    <File Id="TestWCFService.exe" Source="$(var.TestWCFService.TargetDir)TestWCFService.exe" KeyPath="yes"  Vital="yes" DiskId="1"/>
    <ServiceInstall 
      Id="TestWCFService" 
      Name="TestWCFService" 
      Account="LocalSystem" 
      Start="auto" 
      Interactive="no" 
      Type="ownProcess" 
      Vital="yes" 
      ErrorControl="critical" />
    <ServiceControl Id="TestWCFService" Name="TestWCFService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Wait="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id ="TestWCFService.Config" >
    <File Name="TestWCFService.Config" Source = "$(var.TestWCFService.TargetDir)TestWCFService.exe.Config" />
  </Component>
    <File Name="TestUtilities.dll" Source= "$(var.TestWCFService.TargetDir)TestUtilities.dll"  />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="NLog.dll">
    <File Name="NLog.dll" Source= "$(var.TestWCFService.TargetDir)NLog.dll" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

WIX output exe package will be installed successfully(as windows service) and auto started. After that when i test using same WCF test client i don't see service running.

Answer (score 0):

Following answer i got it from WIX community From Joe:

Installed program was looking for TestWCFService.exe.Config but we had deployed same file with different extension name TestWCFService.Config.

```
<Component Id ="TestWCFService.Config" >
<File Name="**TestWCFService.Config**" Source = "$(var.TestWCFService.TargetDir)**TestWCFService.exe.Config**" />
```